# Bugzilla throws error when migrating from an old version

Tags: unix, database-migration, bugzilla

I am trying to migrate from an old bugzilla to a newer one. I installed a newer one on a new server. I run ./checksetup.pl and this is the error:

```
A valid TYPE was not specified for this column (got $VAR1 = {'PRIMARYKEY' =>   1,'ENGINE' => 'MEDIUMSERIAL','NOTNULL' => 1};
) at Bugzilla/DB/Schema.pm line 1975.
Bugzilla::DB::Schema::get_type_ddl('Bugzilla::DB::Schema::Mysql=HASH(0x8                                                           120cd8)', 'HASH(0x8261308)') called at Bugzilla/DB/Schema/Mysql.pm line 380
Bugzilla::DB::Schema::Mysql::get_rename_column_ddl('Bugzilla::DB::Schema                                                           ::Mysql=HASH(0x8120cd8)', 'fielddefs', 'fieldid', 'id') called at Bugzilla/DB.pm                                                            line 1026
Bugzilla::DB::bz_rename_column('Bugzilla::DB::Mysql=HASH(0x7fed8c0)', 'f                                                         ielddefs', 'fieldid', 'id') called at Bugzilla/Install/DB.pm line 69
Bugzilla::Install::DB::update_fielddefs_definition() called at ./checkse                                                         tup.pl line 164
```

Comment: Please can you post the versions you're migrating from and to?

Comment: I am migrating from bugzilla version 2.20 to 5.0.